Comma Usage with "Not... But Rather"
Just wanted to ask this because I feel like I haven't found any answers for this particular issue, but should there be a comma in a sentence that uses a "not... but rather" construction? For example, in the sentence:

The man did not see it as an obstacle but rather as an opportunity for growth.

Just going off of the idea that you should only put a comma before a conjunction if it joins two independent clauses, I feel like no comma would be needed here, and yet I've seen so many people only use this construction with a comma. Which is correct and why?

it's optional. I don't think it's needed with such short phrases, but it might be helpful if the sentence were more complex.

You can add commas anywhere you hear them in speaking the text, or where they'd help break thnigs up. I use them to introduce contrast (but, yet, although): Close, but no cigar. Cash, no checks.

@YosefBaskin Within reason, perhaps. Sometimes you see overzealous transcription of rhetorical timing: "To be, or, not, to be."

Or today: To be. Or. Not. To be.

FWIW, you can drop the rather. But you can also keep it -- some might consider its use here to be an intensifier.

Yes, you should use a comma to separate the words but rather, and, the word after. That is because you are comparing two phrases.

This sounds like personal opinion, and isn't clear in what you're saying. Please edit your post to clarify (using italics or quotation marks to indicate words from the reference sentence), and provide a source for the rule or preferred usage you're describing.
